# How to redirect asp.net to download file from external server

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, server-side

I want to send http request from android app in order to reponse with mp3 file that hosted external server
I am using this code in server side for examle

```
Response.Redirect("https://externalserver-100.mp3");
```

Now instead of getting a file data from client side I got

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://externalserver-100.mp3">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Is there any method to get mp3 file directly.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Generally only browsers follow HTTP redirects. Code generally doesn't follow redirects in my experience. You could change your Android app to read the redirect response, then initiate a new request to the location specified by the redirect. Or you could change your server side to return some other response (such as JSON) representing where to obtain the file, and then the Android app could read that response and use that to initiate a new request. Or you could have your server side app download the file and then write it to its response instead of doing a redirect. Just plan your app a bit.

Comment: Ok, I will change Client side to read the redirect url, Thanks a lot